# View width issue in iPhone 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I have a view on my screen.I have taken iPhone 5 as base screen.I have given following constraints to the view.

```
1.Aspect ration to self.
2.Aspect ratio to parent view.
3.Horizontal center in container.
4.Vertical Spacing.
```

Please check this [image: here]

Here on iPhone 5s the view is not stretched to full width but on iPhone 4 view is not fully stretched.Please tell the issue here.

Comment: Do you get any unsatisfiable constraints error in console? Assuming you want to achieve the effect from iPhone 5, wouldn't constraints for leading/trailing to superview be better, rather than aspect ratios (especially to superview)?

Comment: Laeding and trailing constraints will have fix width & height.

Comment: True. But if so, why are you suprised that you get different results on different screens when you base the dimensions on aspect ratios? :) Could you please provide constant values for these constraints? Especially for the aspect ratios. Or, if possible, could you add the xib/storyboard file in a gist?

Comment: i am using aspect ratio so constant is 320:30 for self,320:568 for superview

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I recreated your constraints and was able to replicate your problem. It is quite simple, and is caused by the aspect ratio constraint to superview.
[image]

As you can see, the constraint is for text field `width` to superview `height` with ratio 320:568. Because we already know the `height` of superview when drawing the textfield, we need to solve this equation, to get text fields `width` :

```
    320        textfield.width
   -----  =  -------------------
    568   =    superview.height
```

So on iPhone 5, the height of superview (in case of full screen view, of course) is 568 - so we know that textfields width should be 320. On iPhone 4 on the other hand the height is 480. Applying to the equation, and solving for `textfield.width` we get 270. So it actually shouldn't be stretched.

There is no "issue" here, and everything is working as it should.

If you want the text field to have the same width as it's superview, you should add an "Equal Widths" constraint.

Let me know if you need further explanations.